# No se puede iterar con el ciclo for... of una variable que almacena un array

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles, find

En este código se tienen condicionales para preguntar al usuario, donde cuando se va a aplicar el método de búsqueda de arrays denominado .find, salta un mensaje por consola donde se lee "Uncaught TypeError: encontrar is not iterable" y cuando voy al último condicional else if resulta que no encuentro el por qué.

Coloqué el puntero del mouse encima del elemento "encontrar" que se itera mediante el ciclo for... of y veo que en la info tipo ventana emergente que lanza VSC aparece al final un "undefined" y luego hice el mismo procedimiento con la declaración de esa variable dos líneas más arriba y observé lo mismo, mientras en las iteraciones con el for... of de las líneas anteriores hago el mismo procedimiento sobre lo que se itera y no sale el undefined...

La cuestión es... ¿por qué el undefined? ¿qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿por qué no se puede iterar ese elemento "encontrar" si realicé mas o menos el mismo procedimiento en los condicionales anteriores y no hubo error? ¿es una cuestión de scope? ¿estoy aplicando mal el método .find en esa línea?

La idea en ese bloque de código es que el usuario encuentre el nombre del animal (según los que están en el primer array "enAdopcion" al principio del código) mediante el dato que introduzca en el prompt

```
const enAdopcion = 

[
  { especie: "perro", sexo: "macho", nombre: "Beethoven", edad: 4},
  { especie: "gato", sexo: "hembra", nombre: "Yoko", edad: 3},
  { especie: "ratón", sexo: "macho", nombre: "Edward", edad: 1},
  { especie: "pez", sexo: "hembra", nombre: "Kathy", edad: 2}
];


enAdopcion.sort((animal1, animal2)=> animal2.edad-animal1.edad)

let tipoDeUsuario = prompt("¿Estás interesado en poner en adopción a una mascota? Responde con un Sí o un No");

if (tipoDeUsuario == "Si" || tipoDeUsuario == "SI" || tipoDeUsuario == "si") {
    const nuevosIngresos = [];
    let   cantidad = 1;
    do{
       let nombre = prompt("Ingresar el nombre del animal");
       let especie = prompt("Ingresar la especie del animal (Perro, Gato, Ratón, Pez, etc.)");
       let sexo = prompt("Ingresar el sexo del animal (escribir Macho o Hembra)");
       let edad = prompt("Ingresar la edad, en meses, del animal");
       let datosDelAnimal = "Especie: " + especie + ", Sexo: "  + sexo + ", Nombre: " + nombre + ", Edad: " + edad + " mes(es).";
       nuevosIngresos.push(datosDelAnimal.toUpperCase());
       console.log(nuevosIngresos.length);
    }while(nuevosIngresos.length != cantidad)
    alert('Estos son los datos del animal que has ingresado: \n' + '\n' + nuevosIngresos.join("\n"));

}else if(tipoDeUsuario == "NO" || tipoDeUsuario == "no" || tipoDeUsuario == "No"){
    let condiciones = prompt("¿Deseas filtrar por condiciones (1), deseas que te mostremos toda la lista de los animales en adopción publicados en nuestra página (2)? Responde 1 O 2, respectivamente.");

    if (condiciones == 1) {
        let tipoDeFiltro = prompt("De acuerdo a qué dato deseas filtrar?:  \n \n 1.- Edad  \n 2.- Sexo  \n 3.- Especie  \n \n Responde ingresando el número correspondiente a la opción en la que estés interesad@");
        
        if (tipoDeFiltro == 1) {
            let numeroMin = prompt("Ingresa la edad mínima, en meses");
            let numeroMax = prompt("Ingresa la edad máxima, en meses");
            const edadDelAnimal = enAdopcion.filter (animal => animal.edad > numeroMin && animal.edad < numeroMax)
            alert("Muy bien! estos son los resultados del filtro aplicado, de mayor a menor edad:")
            for (const animales of edadDelAnimal) {
                alert( "Te presentamos a " + animales.nombre + "; un " + animales.especie + ", de sexo "  + animales.sexo + ", que tiene " + animales.edad + " mes(es) de edad.")
            }
            alert("Si estás interesad@ en alguno de ellos, por favor envíanos tu información, y la del bichito que deseas adoptar, al e-mail adoptemos@gmail.com, y nos pondremos en contacto contigo!")

        }else if (tipoDeFiltro == 2) {
            let femeninoOMasculino = prompt("Ingresa el sexo del animal a adoptar. Escoje entre: femenino o masculino; te pedimos, por favor, escribas todo en minúscula");
            const sexoDelAnimal = enAdopcion.filter (animal => animal.sexo == femeninoOMasculino)
            alert("Muy bien! estos son los resultados del filtro aplicado, de mayor a menor edad: ")
            for (const animales of sexoDelAnimal) {
                alert( "Te presentamos a " + animales.nombre + "; un " + animales.especie + ", de sexo "  + animales.sexo + ", que tiene " + animales.edad + " mes(es) de edad.")
            }
            alert("Si estás interesad@ en alguno de ellos, por favor envíanos tu información, y la del bichito que deseas adoptar, al e-mail adoptemos@gmail.com, y nos pondremos en contacto contigo!")

        }else if (tipoDeFiltro == 3) {
            let tipoDeEspecie = prompt("Ingresa la especie del animal; de momento puedes escoger entre: perro, gato, conejo, hámster; te pedimos, por favor, escribas todo en minúscula");
            const especieDelAnimal = enAdopcion.filter (animal => animal.especie == tipoDeEspecie)
            alert("Muy bien! estos son los resultados del filtro aplicado, de mayor a menor edad: ")
            for (const animales of especieDelAnimal) {
                alert( "Te presentamos a " + animales.nombre + "; un " + animales.especie + ", de sexo "  + animales.sexo + ", que tiene " + animales.edad + " mes(es) de edad.")
            }
            alert("Si estás interesad@ en alguno de ellos, por favor envíanos tu información")

        }else {
            alert("Tu respuesta no está dentro de nuestros archivos; por favor refresca la página e ingresa alguna de las formas previamente solicitadas.")
        }

    }else if (condiciones == 2) {
        alert("A continuación, una lista con los datos de los animalitos en adopción, de mayor a menor edad");
        for (const animal of enAdopcion) {
            alert( "Te presentamos a " + animal.nombre + "; un " + animal.especie + ", de sexo "  + animal.sexo + ", que tiene " + animal.edad + " mes(es) de edad.")
            }
            alert("Si estás interesad@ en alguno de ellos, por favor envíanos tu información")
        
    } else if (condiciones == 3){
        let nombreDelAnimal = prompt("Por favor, ingresa el nombre del animal del que quieres recibir más información");
        const encontrar = enAdopcion.find(animal => animal.nombre == nombreDelAnimal)
        alert("Te dejamos, a continuación, lo que encontramos en nuestros archivos: ")
        for (const animales of encontrar) {
            alert( "Te presentamos a " + animales.nombre + "; un " + animales.especie + ", de sexo "  + animales.sexo + ", que tiene " + animales.edad + " mes(es) de edad.")
        }
        alert("Si estás interesad@ en alguno de ellos, por favor envíanos tu información")
    }
}
```

Comment: Te ocurre ese error porque la constante encontrar no es un array, sino un objeto.

Comment: El método [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) devuelve la primera coincidencia del arreglo que, en tu caso, es un objeto. Si quieres recibir un arreglo con todas las coincidencias, entonces usa el método [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: En efecto, de tanto buscar info, me di cuenta hace unos minutos pero el tema es qué se debería hacer en ese caso... ¿cuál sería la solución para poder utilizar .find adecuadamente? ¿Si no se puede utilizar .find? ¿de que otra manera puedo iterar ese array que está al principio del código desde ese último condicional y encontrar solo un elemento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tienes un arreglo de objetos

```
const enAdopcion = 
[
  { especie: "perro", sexo: "macho", nombre: "Beethoven", edad: 4},
  { especie: "gato", sexo: "hembra", nombre: "Yoko", edad: 3},
  { especie: "ratón", sexo: "macho", nombre: "Edward", edad: 1},
  { especie: "pez", sexo: "hembra", nombre: "Kathy", edad: 2}
];
```

Cuando utilizas el método `find` te retorna un objeto (y solo uno) que coincida con lo especificado por ejemplo

```js
const enAdopcion = [
  { especie: "perro", sexo: "macho", nombre: "Beethoven", edad: 4},
  { especie: "gato", sexo: "hembra", nombre: "Yoko", edad: 3},
  { especie: "ratón", sexo: "macho", nombre: "Edward", edad: 1},
  { especie: "pez", sexo: "hembra", nombre: "Kathy", edad: 2}
];

const llamadoBethoven = enAdopcion.find(animal => animal.nombre== "Beethoven")
console.log(llamadoBethoven)
//resultado : { especie: "perro", sexo: "macho", nombre: "Beethoven", edad: 4}
```

Como es un unico resultado y es un objeto puedes acceder a las propiedades sin necesidad de iterar por ejemplo:

```js
const enAdopcion = [
  { especie: "perro", sexo: "macho", nombre: "Beethoven", edad: 4},
  { especie: "gato", sexo: "hembra", nombre: "Yoko", edad: 3},
  { especie: "ratón", sexo: "macho", nombre: "Edward", edad: 1},
  { especie: "pez", sexo: "hembra", nombre: "Kathy", edad: 2}
];

const llamadoBethoven = enAdopcion.find(animal => animal.nombre== "Beethoven")

console.log(llamadoBethoven.nombre)//Resultado: "Beethoven"
console.log(llamadoBethoven.edad)//Resultado: 4
console.log(llamadoBethoven.sexo)//Resultado: "macho"
```

Distinto fuera si usaras el método `filter` Para encontrar múltiples coincidencias, tendrías que iterar los resultados y podrías hacerlo con `for of`, debido a que `filter` retorna un arreglo de resultados que  cumplieron las condiciones, espero haberte podido ayudar

Por otro lado para iterar objetos te recomiendo usar `for in`

```
for(const item in object){

}
```

Acá te dejo documentación del `for in`[Documentacion for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)  para recorrer objetos

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, pero, creo que sería mejor usar `forEach()`, que está explicado en [esta sección](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#%C2%BFpor_qu%C3%A9_usar_for...in) del enlace que dejaste como referencia de `for(... in ...)`.

Comment: Entiendo por todo lo explicado que... ¿podría guardar en un array cada objeto como una variable y sobre esas variables iterar con .find?

Comment: Pero no entiendo porque guardarías todo en un arreglo, simplemente si quieres obtener varios resultados de una búsqueda usas `filter` como lo venias haciendo antes, si quieres obtener solo un resultado usas `find`, esos métodos retornan (en el caso de `filter` un arreglo de objetos) en el caso de find un objeto, porque el elemento que recorres en tu ejemplo es un array de objetos. LOS OBJETOS  NO SON ITERABLES